# Android Sound in Tabbed Activity

Tags: java, android, audio, tabs, android-tablayout

I have an app with 6 tabs. I followed this tutorial: https://youtu.be/00LLd7qr9sA.
The tab XML files contain a scrollview and some buttons.

I need to make a few of those buttons to make a sound when pressed. I can't seem to use an onClickListener and neither can I just make a function that I can call from the XML file. Can anyone tell me what to put in here:

```
package com.ggblbl.soundsintabs;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab4 extends Fragment {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab4makesounds, container, false);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main activity's code?

Comment: It's in the tutorial I linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code to add click listener to buttons in the fragment and play sound file.

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab4makesounds, container, false);
        Button btnOne = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.YourButtonId);

       btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                     mediaPlayer.release();
                     mediaPlayer = null;
                  }

                  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.your_sound);
                  mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

I am assuming that your sound file is in res/raw/ folder

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(100);

         // add your sound here
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```